# How to make separator between values from different select options?

Tags: javascript

I've got this:

```js
function generate() {
  var color = $("#color option:selected").map(function(){return this.value}).get().join('-');
  var size = $("#size option:selected").map(function(){return this.value}).get().join('-');
                                        

  // Final URL
  var result = 'https://weneve.com/en/59-wall-concrete-tiles?q=';
  color ? result += 'Color-'+color : null;
  size ? result += 'Size-'+size : null;
                            
  window.open(result,'_blank');
}
```

But in the FINAL URL if someone chooses Value=Color and Value=Size the values are next to each other without any space. How can I separate them with a comma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editing answer as recommended...  As other follow-on answers have commented, we generally use array.join to handle this kind of stuff.   But if you are only ever going to have 2 parameters (color and size) then you could just add the comma if both color and size were selected by the user.  The code below just adds one additional statement using the same ternary operator format you used for color and size options with the exception that the condition check is for both (color && size).  If both evaluate to true, then add the comma to the result string.

```
// Final URL
var result = 'https://weneve.com/en/59-wall-concrete-tiles?q=';
color ? result += 'Color-'+color : null;
(color && size) ? result += ',' : null;
size ? result += 'Size-'+size : null;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm very appreciative.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of concat immediately you can keep you query params in array. Than - concat it with join method.

```
var queryParams = [];
if(color) queryParams.push('Color-' + color);
if(size) queryParams.push('Size-' + size);

var queryParamsString = queryParams.join(',');
var url = 'https://weneve.com/en/59-wall-concrete-tiles';
var finalUrl = queryParamsString ? url + '?q=' + queryParamsString : url;
```

But if I were you I would have a look to the URL type https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL to construct more understandable and elegant code.

Answer (score 1):

Think about it this way: when working with a list of things where you don't yet know the final length, put those things in an `Array`. When you're ready to display text that depends on the things that are in that array, then convert the array to a `String`, with your desired character(s) between the things.

You're already using `.join()` earlier in your code. You'll use that to add commas in your last step.

```js
function generate() {
  // create empty array
  var queryParams = [];

  var color = $("#color option:selected").map(function(){
    return this.value
  }).get().join('-');

  if (color) {
    queryParams.push(color);
  }

  var size = $("#size option:selected").map(function(){
    return this.value
  }).get().join('-');

  if (size) {
    queryParams.push(size);
  }                                        

  // Final URL
  var urlOptions = queryParams.join(',');
  var result = `https://weneve.com/en/59-wall-concrete-tiles?q=${params}`;
                            
  window.open(result,'_blank');
}
```